# How do I deserialize json into PropertyType?

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net

I'm trying to create a new instance of a property by deserializing a `json` string.  The call to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string)` works when I explicitly state the type of `T`:

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Resource>(propertyValue.ToString());
```

But I'd like to pass it `PropertyInfo.PropertyType`:

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<prop.PropertyType>(propertyValue.ToString());
```

I get "type or namespace 'prop' could not be found."  This doesn't make sense to me, I thought that `PropertyType` is a `Type`.

Comment: Generics don't work like that.

Comment: @SLaks Ok, is there an alternative I can try?  A different approach?

Comment: Here `PropertyType` is a property that *holds* a `Type`; it is not a type itself.  Generics must be able to be resolved at compile time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take the overload that does accept a type parameter

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            propertyValue.ToString(), 
            prop.PropertyType);
```

foo will be of type `object` in this case. This solves your question but you are still left with a reference to a type that is not of your `prop.PropertyType`.